# How to pop open a forms template to enter multiple values

Tags: forms

In this particular scenario, there exists a function with multiple arguments:

```lisp
(defun example-fn (arg &opional one two three four five)
  "Doc-string."
  (interactive "P")
  ;; ...
  ;; ...
  ;; ...
    (list arg one two three four five))
```

I am looking for an Emacs equivalent of a form to enter multiple fields, with a submit button to pass all of the fields as arguments to `example-fn`.  Using the `TAB` key to cycle forwards between entry fields, and `S-TAB` to cycle backwards between entry fields, would be most helpful.  Pressing the `RET` key when the `SUBMIT` button is selected would also be helpful.  How can I do this all within Emacs?

[Some initial brainstorming of ideas include something like `M-x customize` or a webpage displayed within Emacs; however, there may be something more specific that already exists for this particular purpose ...]

Comment: There is the [Emacs Widget library](https://gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/index.html). I believe Customize uses it but I'm not sure (I checked and it does).

Comment: I am not sure what you would like exactly, but there is also the [transient](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/transient.html) package, which is great for this type of work.