# Prepend custom field names when inserting a multi-list widget

Tags: widget

I am trying to resolve a related question relating to creating a simple form to input and return various fields:  [How to pop open a forms template to enter multiple values](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70049/2287)  To that end, I defined a widget, using a modified version of the multiple fields with `INS` and `DEL`.  I will be using a fixed number of fields, and have no need for `INS` and `DEL`.  How can I prepend the field names to each field inserted into the buffer, e.g., `field_one` through `field_five`?

**BEFORE**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**AFTER**

```
field_one:   1
field_two:   2
field_three: 3
field_four:  4
field_five:  5
```

```lisp
(define-widget 'my-editable-list 'default
  "A variable list of widgets of the same type."
  :convert-widget 'widget-types-convert-widget
  :copy 'widget-types-copy
  :offset 12
  :format "%v\n"
  :format-handler 'widget-editable-list-format-handler
  :entry-format "%v"
  :value-create 'widget-editable-list-value-create
  :value-get 'widget-editable-list-value-get
  :validate 'widget-children-validate
  :match 'widget-editable-list-match
  :match-inline 'widget-editable-list-match-inline
  :insert-before 'widget-editable-list-insert-before
  :delete-at 'widget-editable-list-delete-at)

(defun example-fn ()
  (interactive)
  "Doc-string."
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*TEST*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (erase-buffer)
      (widget-create 'my-editable-list
                     :format "%v\n"
                     :value '("1" "2" "3" "4" "5")
                     '(editable-field
                       :value-to-external
                       (lambda (wid value)
                         (if (widget-get wid :parent)
                             value
                           (message "This is not currently used."))))))
    (display-buffer buffer)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’re going about it the wrong way. Instead of making something complicated and meta, just be explicit:

```lisp
(define-widget 'bibtex-entry-alist 'lazy
  "Format of `bibtex-BibTeX-entry-alist' and friends."
  :type '(repeat (group (string :tag "Entry type")
                        (string :tag "Documentation")
                        (repeat :tag "Required fields" …))))
```

Just make five string inputs inside a group. This is especially true if the field labels are always the same.